# angular-chart not showing Pie Chart

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I am having an issue within my AngularJS application not rendering the Pie Chart from angular-chart, which uses Chart.JS.

I have registered chart.js as a dependency within my angular module as following:

```
    var app = angular.module("uniSurvey",
                        ["common.services",
                            "ui.router",
                            "chart.js"]);
```

Then within my view, I have added the Pie Chart canvas following their documentation:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in resultsDetails.items">
        <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie chart-xs"
                chart-data="resultsDetails.data"
                chart-labels="resultsDetails.label"
                chart-legend="resultsDetails.legend"></canvas>
</div>
```

And within my controller for that view, I have set the data required by the chart as following:

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular
    .module("uniSurvey")
    .controller("ResultsDetailsController", ["$stateParams", "resultResource", ResultsDetailsController]);

function ResultsDetailsController($stateParams, resultResource) {
    var resultsDetails = this;
    resultsDetails.currentSurveyId = $stateParams.id;

    resultsDetails.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
    resultsDetails.data = [300, 500, 100];
    resultsDetails.legend = true;

    resultsDetails.items = [];
}
```

}());

With the current setup, I get the following error:

> angular.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
>       at v (angular-chart.min.js:323)
>       at d (angular-chart.min.js:191)
>       at angular-chart.min.js:150
>       at n.$digest (angular.js:17073)
>       at n.$apply (angular.js:17337)
>       at l (angular.js:11572)
>       at H (angular.js:11778)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.u.onload (angular.js:11711)

Any ideas of what steps I may have missed please?

Comment: have you included the `angular-chart.min.js` dependency on your page?

Comment: @Maverick976 - Yes I had done that, included my silly mistake as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a silly mistake, it was "resultsDetails.labels" not "resultsDetails.label". Since it's the first time I'm using angular-chart I thought this is something else, not the most basic of things.